# Customizing buttons in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Where can i get customized buttons that are free to download that can be used with WinForms? I am currently using C# (Visual Studio) for a desktop applications and my aim is to create a good looking UI.

I am looking for good looking next, back buttons etc.

Edit 1:

For e.g MS Access have the following button for previous 
[image].What is the equivalent for windows form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use BindingNavigator**

You can put a [`BindingNavigator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zhc8d2f(v=vs.110).aspx) component on your form. You can also [customize colors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229724(v=vs.110).aspx) using custom color tables to render in office style. You can find some famous color tables here in [ToolStrip Customizer](https://toolstripcustomizer.codeplex.com/).

**Use Button with png image from Visual Studio Image Library**

You can download [`Visual Studio Image Library`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825) and use standard visual studio png images on your buttons.

[image]

In the above picture, top component is `BindingNavigator` and other components are buttons with standard icons from `Visual Studio Image Library`.

You can also inherit from `Button` and override `OnPaint` and draw button background using `PathGradientBrush` or `LinearGradientBrush` to have vista style glass buttons. You can find an example [here](http://timtrott.co.uk/vista-style-glass-buttons/).